# Select a date range to filter a DGV using RowFilter

Tags: windows, vb.net, date, datagridview, datepicker

I am taking the dates through datepicker controls, but not achieving any success, anyone have any suggestions.

I tryed:

```
Dim fromDate As New DateTime(startdate_picker_search_supplierinvoice.Text)
Dim toDate As New DateTime(enddate_picker_search_supplierinvoice.Text)

query &= "supplier_invoice_date >= '" & fromDate & "' AND supplier_invoice_date <= '" & toDate & "'"
invoicesresults_datagrid_search_supplierinvoice.DataSource = SelectDataTable(dt, query)
```

**Error:** Conversion from string "Tuesday, July 17, 2012" to type 'Long' is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `.Text` property which is returning the full written out date.  Instead use:

```
Dim fromDate As DateTime = startdate_picker_search_supplierinvoice.Value
Dim toDate As DateTime = enddate_picker_search_supplierinvoice.Value
```

and then the `.ToString' extension.

```
query &= "supplier_invoice_date >= '" & fromDate.ToShortDateString & "' AND supplier_invoice_date <= '" & toDate.ToShortDateString & "'"
invoicesresults_datagrid_search_supplierinvoice.DataSource = SelectDataTable(dt, query)
```

Comment: @JohnNuñez, I fixed the full problem. See changed answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but when trying to set the dates get this error: Can not recognize the string as a valid DateTime. :(

Comment: @JohnNuñez, Are you getting this error message in the declaration of `fromDate` or in the `query` expression?

Comment: I get this error into the SelectDataTable Function, please look this: http://i45.tinypic.com/r0t6jl.png

Comment: @JohnNuñez, I removed the `#` delimiters (I had MS Access on the brain, sorry) and returned the single quote.  Also, I replaced the `.ToString` with `.ToShortDateString`.

Comment: Very well already I do not obtain some error anymore, but when I try to select a range of date 2 records exist in this range but i do not obtain anything. http://i49.tinypic.com/23j1lrc.png

Comment: @JohnNuñez, Are any of the dates the same as the `toDate`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14014/discussion-between-john-nunez-and-holger-brandt)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are declaring a DateTime object, and the constructor you are using is expecting (ticks as Long). You should be using

```
Dim toDate As DateTime
toDate = enddate_picker_search_supplierinvoice.Value
```

Note that .Value returns the date, rather than a String.

Comment: I made the changes into the code, but now i get this error: Can not recognize the string as a valid DateTime. Thanks